# Authorization on site objective-c

Tags: objective-c, https, authorization

how can I get HTTPS authorization on site https://uslugi.beeline.ru not using UIWebView from iOS?

Their APIs I unfortunately do not have = (

Please help, and sorry for my english, it's Google Translate.

P.S. Username and password to login I can not give because important information is stored there.

P.P.S Maybe there are ways to fill out a form via http UIWebView, but so that it loads only source without pictures?

Comment: Use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), for instance. You would need to build the requests programmatically. For this you should have the API specifiation.

Comment: @ilmiacs And without the API does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to know the API for the POST or GET (and parameters of the body data). Check the documentation(Configuring Authentication point): [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests.html)